# JDeveloper 10g rename and resize columns in forms

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a kind of a strange problem in JDeveloper 10g when working with forms:
**I can't select single column and rename it**. Actually I can't select ANY element on the form besides whole form. So, my question is how to select single element on the form, for example column "Ime", and how to rename it?

[image: selection of single column in for]

Another question is how to effectively resize and position fields on the form?
For example, even if I select it here and resize it:

[image: resize and reposition of a field]

When  I start the form it reverts back?

Answer (score 2):

Also see if you have access to the item you want to change in the structure pane window on the bottom of the left in your screen capture.